# Linear Regression - Append Predicted Values to Same dataset

Tags: r, lm, predict

I recently started with R programming. This is my dataset

```
WeekOfYear  Production
         1      202612
         2      245633
         3      299653
         4      252612
         5      299633
         6      288993
         7      254653
         8      288612
         9      277733
        10      245633
```

I need to predict “Production” values for the remaining Weeks of the Year

```
relation<-lm(Production~WeekOfYear,dataset)

predict(relation,data.frame(WeekOfYear=c(11)))
```

How to append predicted values for week nos 11 to 52 (end of year) to the same dataset like below

```
WeekOfYear  Production
        1       202612
        2       245633
        3       299653
        4       252612
        5       299633
        6       288993
        7       254653
        8       288612
        9       277733
       10       245633
       11   predicted value
       12   predicted value
```

so on

-OR-

```
WeekOfYear  Production  Regression
         1      202612  fitted value
         2      245633  fitted value
         3      299653  fitted value
         4      252612  fitted value
         5      299633  fitted value
         6      288993  fitted value
         7      254653  fitted value
         8      288612  fitted value
         9      277733  fitted value
        10      245633  fitted value
        11              predicted value
        12              predicted value
        13              predicted value
        14              predicted value
         .
         .
        52              predicted value
```

Comment: `cbind('WeekOfYear' = 11:52, 'Production' = predict(relation, newdata = data.frame(WeekOfYear = 11:52)))`. then `rbind` that to your original data.

Comment: sometimes I may have data for more than 11 weeks, is there a way to dynamically set this week number? 52 is always a fixed number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
relation <- lm(Production ~ WeekOfYear, dat)

WeekOfYear <- 1:52
predict(relation, data.frame(WeekOfYear))

dat2 <- data.frame(WeekOfYear, regression = predict(relation, data.frame(WeekOfYear)))

merge(dat, dat2, by = 'WeekOfYear', all.y = TRUE)
```

The result:

```
   WeekOfYear Production regression
1           1     202612   250517.6
2           2     245633   253864.1
3           3     299653   257210.5
4           4     252612   260557.0
5           5     299633   263903.5
6           6     288993   267249.9
7           7     254653   270596.4
8           8     288612   273942.9
9           9     277733   277289.3
10         10     245633   280635.8
11         11         NA   283982.3
12         12         NA   287328.7

----

51         51         NA   417840.9
52         52         NA   421187.4
```

Answer (score 2):

To append your values you can use the following

```
test_data <- data.frame(WeekOfYear=11:52, Production = rep(0, 52-11+1))
test_data$Production <- predict(relation,test_data)

df = rbind(df, test_data)
```

where I have defined with `df` your data Frame

```
df = data.frame(WeekOfYear =
c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
Production = c(202612,245633,299653,252612,299633,288993,254653,288612, 277733,245633))
```

this will give you this behaviour (plot put together very quickly)

[image]

I am not sure anyway that your data follow a linear behaviour but you may know your data better...

Comment: You may consider replacing `rep(0, 52 - 11 + 1)` with `rep_len(0, length(11:52))`

Comment: Thanks @bouncyball. I wrote the code in 2 minutes and did not think of optimizing ;-)

Comment: I just need to add charaters to be able to write this: :-D